# Mongoid doesn't delete Mongo objects

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I am using Sinatra and Mongoid to access a MongoDB.  Most of it works well except when I try to delete an object, the object gets deleted but appears to remain in the database.

```
 u = User.find(user_id)
 u.delete
```

This seems to work and does not generate an error, but when I check the database using the Mongo console to confirm this, the object is still there.  The user object is not in a capped collection.

```
 u = User.find(user_id)
 u.delete
 u = User.find(user_id)
```

This change does generate an error, which means the object was successfully deleted.  Nonetheless, in the Mongo console, a find() call on the users collection still shows the object.

Comment: Do you have `include Mongoid:Paranoia` in your model? The default behavior shouldn't be using deleted_at. See http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html

Comment: Thanks Ted.  You are correct Paranoia is in the model and I need to use "u.delete!" to truly expunge the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the MongoDB object is not erased from the database, a "deleted_at" parameter is added to the object which indicates when it was "deleted".  Afterward the object will not be found in searches.

Comment: Thanks Lior.  You were correct that the "deleted_at" was added to the object.  My developer include paranoia in the user model to prevent deletions.  I learned that to really delete the object, I must use "u.delete!" and not the standard "user.delete" which I had been using.